# File upload not working.It gives error 3 every time

Tags: php, fpm

Am trying to upload a file using nginx fpm but its keep giving me error 3

Here is the [configuration](http://dpaste.com/0D6RER8) which I set for it.

Any idea or suggestion for it?

I already did my homework to resolve this problem.

I have checked below possibilities as well.

1. There is lots of space on a server
2. There is no any permission problem with a folder.

**Configuration Details :**

```
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");

ini_set("max_execution_time","300");

ini_set("max_input_time","300");

ini_set('upload_max_filesize',"20M");

ini_set('post_max_size',"21M");
```

Comment: are you uploading files from iOS?

Comment: where is the code that does the upload and the html that you use??

Comment: some suggestion: try `client_max_body_size 8M;` in `Nginx configuration` to set `0`. `client_max_body_size 0;`

Comment: @BilalAhmed : Thanks for reply. Nope am doing it from web portal.

Comment: @RamRaider : https://github.com/iNextrix/ASTPP/blob/v3.6/web_interface/astpp/application/modules/rates/controllers/rates.php in this link you will get the function origination_rate_preview_file which is showing error in php and html file : https://github.com/iNextrix/ASTPP/blob/v3.6/web_interface/astpp/application/modules/rates/views/view_import_origination_rate.php

Comment: @BilalAhmed : WIll do changes and update you

Comment: @BilalAhmed : Thanks for answer .I set value 0 as suggested and it works 
Really appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments

try `client_max_body_size 8M;` in Nginx configuration to set `0`.
Like

```
 client_max_body_size 0;
```